# Artifacts checkin/checkout from bitbucket server though jenkins

Tags: jenkins, bitbucket

I am using ant script to build my code and keeping it in zip file.I am using bit bucket server as repository.Can anyone please let me know in below two question:-

1. By which plugin we can checkin this build artifact back to bitbucket repository
2. By which plugin we can download the build artifacts from bitbucket repository 
   on the remote machine using jenkins.

Thanks in advance!!!!

Comment: What OS do you use for Jenkins server?

Comment: @Gluttton:- I am using Oracle linux for the jenkins as well as for bitbucket.

Comment: So you can do anything using `Execute shell` build step. And you don't need any special plug-in.

Comment: To perform build step on remote host you need `Execute shell on remote host using ssh` build step which became available after installing ssh plug-in (https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/SSH+plugin).

Comment: @Glutton: Ok.But we need to checkin back the build artifact back to bitbucket repository as well.So for that any plugin is there?

Comment: If you're looking for proper dependency / artifact management, then Artifactory may be a better fit than bitbucket: https://www.jfrog.com/open-source/